# reinstall gitlab on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: gitlab

I use `./bitnami-gitlab-8.9.6-0-linux-x64-installer.run` to install with `root` account.
First time I install it successfully but I install it in the worng floder. So I use `uninstall` to uninstall it.

Second time I kill the apache which bind 80 port and delete user gitlab_ci.
Then I install it again in the same way,but another floder.This time it failed. How to solve it.

```
Installing
 0% ______________ 50% ______________ 100%
 #####Unable to create symbolic link /opt/gitlab/postgresql/bin/invproj -> proj
Abort, Retry, Ignore ? [A/r/i]r

Unable to create symbolic link /opt/gitlab/postgresql/bin/invproj -> proj
Abort, Retry, Ignore ? [A/r/i]i

Unable to create symbolic link /opt/gitlab/postgresql/bin/postmaster -> postgres
Abort, Retry, Ignore ? [A/r/i]a


Error: There has been an error.
Unable to create symbolic link /opt/gitlab/postgresql/bin/postmaster -> postgres
Press [Enter] to continue:
```

Comment: Investigate why it failed to crate symlink. Does it already exist?

Comment: I don not know how to delete them.  I don not know  where they are.The error report is too simple.@agilob

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by  killing and uninstalling through software manager. Then reinstall worked perfectly.